# WordPress - Getting my columns to resize automatically using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Wordpress template that uses Bootstrap 2.3.1.
I currently have my two areas set up via an SPAN4 and SPAN8.
The resolution is locked at 1170px, therefore the `lg` component of Bootstrap is not needed to be configured.

I would like some help with the areas shown in red, as to how to configure my nested columns, so they work properly. They are within an area already defined as Span 8, so in effect, it is an 8 wide grid that needs to be configured to show 3 columns on medium devices, 2 columns on small devices and 1 column on the extra small devices.

I am relatively new to CSS, but have some understanding of basic coding, it's just doing my head in at the moment.
The attached picture show what I am after
[My Wordpress layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TbPq.jpg)

I can't seem to get any bootstrap to work with the sizes I would like to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use bootstrap **version 3**

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

unlike version 2, it has classes like `col-lg-*` `col-md-*` `col-sm-*` `col-xs-*`, which can get your job done more easily.

trying to understanding your problem.

> [image]

try the demo code below to see if it's the layout you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<style>
  .b {
    border: 1px solid #333;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">aside</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      main
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="b">
            <h3>.col-md-4.col-sm-6</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="b">
            <h3>.col-md-4.col-sm-6</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="b">
            <h3>.col-md-4.col-sm-6</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd spent all afternoon adding what I didn't realise were bootstrap3 classes such as those, and had them all set for the columns to automatically resize as per screen size, but didn't realise what version they applied to. Have now added in bootstrap 3 functionality, and can now use those classes you have specified.

Comment: I have it running bootstrap 3, but the columns are not stacking the way I'd like them to. Currently each of the items are in a seperate div, nothing is nested, and I get column three underneath column two, so it becomes a longer list. I'd like them to redistribute the list evenly as it stacks the columns as the screen size gets smaller